# why tag changed in tableview to reuseing cells

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, sqlite

I am creating custom cell contain `UILabel` , `UIImageView` ,using constant tag for `UILabel` , `UIImageView` using dynamic tag, the table have 11 cells, the first 7 cells loading correctly, the 8, 9, 10, 11 cell image view change when I am changing the 1, 2, 3, 4, cell respectively in the table, also the tags are same in the cells, I am using the images to check box in table,`UITapGestureRecognizer` used to change imageview in the table,

I am using this code.....

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        UIImageView *imageview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 12, 20, 20)];
        imageview.tag=n;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageview]; 
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tabimage:)];
        imageview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        [imageview addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        imageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.jpeg"];

        UILabel *titleLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 2, 260,26)];
        titleLabel.tag=222;
        titleLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];

        UILabel *dateLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 31, 260, 13)];
        dateLabel.tag=333;
        dateLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
        dateLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
         [cell.contentView addSubview:dateLabel];
    }
    UIImageView *imageview1=(UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:n];
    if([array containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:imageview1.tag]]) {
       imageview1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.jpeg"];  
    } else {
       imageview1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.jpeg"];   
    }

    UILabel *titlelable=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:222];
    titlelable.text=[task objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSLog(@"%i",indexPath.section);

    UILabel *dateLabel=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:333];
    dateLabel.text=[date objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    n++;
    return  cell;
}

- (void)tabimage:(id)sender {
    UIImageView *iv=(UIImageView *)[sender view];
    int i=iv.tag;
    NSLog(@"------------%i",i);
   if (iv.image==[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.jpeg"]) {
       iv.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.jpeg"];
       [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
   } else {
      iv.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.jpeg"];  
      [array removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }
  }
```

Comment: ... and? What's your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am getting solution for my app,

to using dynamic cell identifier in my code

```
NSString *CellIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i-%i", indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
```

Comment: This is exactly what my answer was, why didn't you accepted mine then.

Answer (score 8):

You should change your cell identifier from static to dynamic that will solve your problem.

You should replace this

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

with this

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %d"], indexPath.row, indexPath.section];
```

Comment: it`s work correctly NSString *CellIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i-%i", indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

Answer (score 4):

Whatever problem you see, use of that "`n`" is most probably the problem. There is no good reason to use a shared variable to tag (and retrieve) views on table view cells.

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is called many times, it may be called several times for the same cell, and sometimes it finds a cell to reuse, and sometimes not.

I have of course no idea what `n` is, and how you use it elsewhere in your code, but you change it with every call here, and you cannot make assumptions when this method is called, so it's worthless.

You know for sure that every cell has one image with that tag, but if it will ever be accessible after the first run through this method or not is totally undefined, so with every reuse you basically get random behavior (either a fresh new cell or a reused one with a tag you don't know).

Ask yourself (or maybe at SO in another question): What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Agreed, I don't see that `n` is set *anywhere* in the code, so even with that massive block of code we can't totally tell what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest subclass the UITableViewCell add there all your custom elements, create setters for it. And in cellForRowAtIndexPath just call your setters.

Answer (score 0):

As you are setting tag to imageview in if(cell == nil) block means tag will be set when cell is getting created. In your case 7 cells are getting created after that cells are reused by dequeuing. Hence for 8 onwards previously created cells will be used. This is why your tags are same as 1,2,3...for 8,9,10...cells.

Well, Alex suggested standard way to do it. But if you have not used custom cells yet, you can try this-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UIImageView *imageview = nil;    
    if(cell){
        for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews){
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
                    imageview = (UIImageView*)view;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        imageview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 12, 20, 20)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageview]; 
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tabimage:)];
        imageview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        [imageview addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        imageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.jpeg"];

        UILabel *titleLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 2, 260,26)];
        titleLabel.tag=222;
        titleLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];

        UILabel *dateLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 31, 260, 13)];
        dateLabel.tag=333;
        dateLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
        dateLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
         [cell.contentView addSubview:dateLabel];
    }
    imageview.tag=n;
    if([array containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:imageview.tag]]) {
       imageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.jpeg"];  
    } else {
       imageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.jpeg"];   
    }

    UILabel *titlelable=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:222];
    titlelable.text=[task objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSLog(@"%i",indexPath.section);

    UILabel *dateLabel=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:333];
    dateLabel.text=[date objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    n++;
    return  cell;
}
```